# Like the List created and not the list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, rating

Right now there is a setting called RatingList which gives the experience of Likes/Vote for a list item.
Does similar experience exist for List as well?

Comment: As per my knowledge, there is no functionality like that OOTB.

Comment: OP are you still alive? :) if any of the asnwers helped you please vote and mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Online Team site, there is still OOB list rating settings. You can change the settings inside List/Library settings.

[image]

For communication site, the feature is not available.

Similar question: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-list-rating-settings-missing-in-list/e4d5fbc0-ea5e-46fa-9f4b-720ae5cedd4c

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/communication-site-document-library-rating-settings/m-p/87968

Answer (score 0):

Yes you sure can. Open the list Settings and you will see an option for Ratings Settings. There are various different options you can choose. This will work on most list types.